# Multiple domains powered by one rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, hosting

I am creating a blogging-like application where we allow our customers to use their own custom domain names such as domainexample.com, so each different domain serves the same application but with different content.

However I am struggling to figure out how to set this up on a production server. If my production server has a static IP then I can surely just set an a-record on each domain to the ip of the production server.

But what if the production server does not have a static IP. For example if we want to host it on heroku or engineyard? I have seen a few solutions online that require using rewrite rules but they require server restarts and cant really dynamically add and remove new domains as new users sign up. Does anyone know any good solutions to let multiple domains hit one rails app?

Comment: heroku has a ["wildcard domains"](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#wildcard_domains) solution

Comment: that seems to be only available for subdomains

Comment: Probably, you will have to update DNS record, but CNAME, not A.

Comment: Ah, I was sure you were talking about subdomains. There's no problem directing multiple domains to the same IP. in Heroku, you'll need to direct them all to the same IP, and add these domains to the same app through their admin panel (or `heroku domains:add newhost.com` if using their Gem)

Answer (score 5):

Heroku isn't your only option. If you can anticipate your customer's domains, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737007/314318). If you can't, Rails routes [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) and a combination of the accepted answer to the question linked above should get you where you need to be going. Sounds like you wouldn't want to restart your server--so no editing of the routes. You might also make [domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323643/rails-route-to-model-instance-by-domain-name) part of your models, or distinguish at the [controller level](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-host) or use URL rewriting in your web-server layer.

The problem, as I see it, is that Rails breaks its mantra of opinion over configuration here. There are *many* ways of serving up from multiple domains. That might be an intrinsic complexity, but the Rails Guides could at least document one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your customers just CNAME to your domain or create the A record to your IP and you don't handle TLS termination for these custom domains, your app will not support HTTPS, and without it, your app won't work in modern browsers on these custom domains.

You need to set up a TLS termination reverse proxy in front of your webserver. This proxy can be run on a separate machine but you can run it on the same machine as the webserver.

#### CNAME vs A record

If your customers want to have your app on their subdomain, e.g. `app.customer.com` they can create a CNAME `app.customer.com` pointing to your proxy.

If they want to have your app on their root domain, e.g. `customer.com` then they'll have to create an A record on `customer.com` pointing to your proxy's IP. Make sure this IP doesn't change, ever!

#### How to handle TLS termination?

To make TLS termination work, you'll have to issue TLS certificates for these custom domains. You can use Let's Encrypt for that. Your proxy will see the `Host` header of the incoming request, e.g. `app.customer1.com` or `customer2.com` etc., and then it will decide which TLS certificate to use by checking the SNI.

The proxy can be set up to automatically issue and renew certificates for these custom domains. On the first request from a new custom domain, the proxy will see it doesn't have the appropriate certificate. It will ask Let's Encrypt for a new certificate. Let's Encrypt will first issue a challenge to see if you manage the domain, and since the customer already created a CNAME or A record pointing to your proxy, that tells Let's Encrypt you indeed manage the domain, and it will let you issue a certificate for it.

To issue and renew certificates automatically, I'd recommend using Caddyserver, greenlock.js, OpenResty (Nginx).

tl;dr on what happens here;
Caddyserver listens on 443 and 80, it receives requests, issues, and renews certificates automatically, proxies traffic to your backend.

#### How to handle it on my backend

Your proxy is terminating TLS and proxying requests to your backend. However, your backend doesn't know who is the original customer behind the request. This is why you need to tell your proxy to include additional headers in proxied requests to identify the customer. Just add `X-Serve-For: app.customer.com` or `X-Serve-For: customer2.com` or whatever the `Host` header is of the original request.

Now when you receive the proxied request on the backend, you can read this custom header and you know who is the customer behind the request. You can implement your logic based on that, show data belonging to this customer, etc.

#### More

Put a load balancer in front of your fleet of proxies for higher availability. You'll also have to use distributed storage for certificates and Let's Encrypt challenges. Use AWS ECS or EBS for automated recovery if something fails, otherwise, you may be waking up in the middle of the night restarting machines, or your proxy manually.

Alternatively, there have been a few services like [this](https://saascustomdomains.com) recently that allow you to add custom domains to your app without running the infrastructure yourself.

If you need more detail you can DM me on Twitter [@dragocrnjac](https://twitter.com/dragocrnjac)